# Read/write/append to CSV using python

Tags: python, csv

I am attempting to use the CSV module of python to modify a CSV file.  The file represents a stock and lists (as columns) the date, open price, high price, low price, close price, and volume for the day.  What I would like to do is create multiple new columns by performing algebra on the existing data.  For instance, I would like to create a column for the percentage from the open price to the high price for any given day and another for the percentage change from yesterday's close to today's close (no end in sight here, as of now thinking of about 10 columns to add).

Is there a compact way to do this?  As of now, I am opening the original file and reading into a list(s) the values of interest.  Then writing onto some temp file the modified values using that list(s).  Then writing onto some new file using a for loop and adding the rows from each spreadsheet.  Then writing the entire contents of that new file onto the original csv, as I would like to maintain the name of the csv (ticker.csv).

Hopefully I have made my issue clear.  If you would like any clarification or further details, please do not hesitate.

edit: I have included a snippet of the code for one function below.  The function seeks to create a new column that has the percent change from yesterday's close to today's close.

```
def add_col_pchange(ticker):
    """
    Add column with percent change in closing price.
    """
    original = open('file1', 'rb')
    reader = csv.reader(original)
    reader.next()
    close = list()
    for row in reader:
        # build list of close values; entries from left to right are reverse chronological
        # index 4 corresponds to "Close" column
        close.append(float(row[4])
    original.close()

    new = open(file2, 'wb')
    writer = csv.writer(new)
    writer.writerow(["Percent Change"])
    pchange = list()
    for i in (0, len(close)-1):
        x = (close[i]-close[i+1])/close[i+1]
        pchange.append(x)
    new.close()

    # open original and new csv's as read, write out to some new file.  
    # later, copy that entire file to original csv in order to maintain 
    # original csv's name and include new data
```

Comment: Alas, it's not clear (at least to me).  However, I would guess that you only have to make one pass to read the data into memory and one other pass to write it out again -- I doubt the intermediate files are really necessary.  To provide a clearer explanation post at least the outline of your code.

Comment: @LarryLustig -- edit made.  Thanks for the reply!

Comment: You might want to consider using the Pandas library. You can read in the csv file as a dataframe, create a new Series, and append the series to the dataframe before writing it out.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

```
def add_col_pchange(ticker):
    """
    Add column with percent change in closing price.
    """
    # always use with to transparently manage opening/closing files
    with open('ticker.csv', 'rb') as original:
        spam = csv.reader(original)
        headers = spam.next()  # get header row
        # get all of the data at one time, then transpose it using zip
        data = zip(*[row for row in spam])
    # build list of close values; entries from left to right are reverse chronological
    # index 4 corresponds to "Close" column
    close = data[4]  # the 5th column has close values

    # use map to process whole column at one time
    f_pchange = lambda close0, close1: 100 * (float(close0) - float(close1)) / float(close1)
    Ndays = len(close)  # length of table
    pchange = map(f_pchange, close[:-1], close[1:])  # list of percent changes
    pchange = (None,) + tuple(pchange)  # add something for the first or last day
    headers.append("Percent Change")  # add column name to headers
    data.append(pchange)
    data = zip(*data)  # transpose back to rows

    with open('ticker.csv', 'wb') as new:
        spam = csv.writer(new)
        spam.writerow(headers)  # write headers
        for row in data:
            spam.writerow(row)

    # open original and new csv's as read, write out to some new file.  
    # later, copy that entire file to original csv in order to maintain 
    # original csv's name and include new data
```

You should check out either [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/); you could use `loadtxt()` and vector math, but @lightalchemist is right, [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) was designed just for this.